# Does machine learning framework caffe support different data type precisions?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, caffe

I am currently playing with the CaffeNet C++ image classification example. By default, this example using float. And here were the results I got:

```
--cat--
Classification time: 0.8267 seconds
0.3134 - "n02123045 tabby, tabby cat"
0.2380 - "n02123159 tiger cat"
0.1235 - "n02124075 Egyptian cat"
0.1003 - "n02119022 red fox, Vulpes vulpes"
0.0715 - "n02127052 lynx, catamount"

--dog--
Classification time: 0.8259 seconds
0.4228 - "n02106662 German shepherd, German shepherd dog, German police dog, alsatian"
0.1344 - "n02109961 Eskimo dog, husky"
0.0914 - "n02091467 Norwegian elkhound, elkhound"
0.0642 - "n02110063 malamute, malemute, Alaskan malamute"
0.0532 - "n02110185 Siberian husky"
```

After I changed every float to double in classification.cpp. I was hoping I could get similar accuracy with longer computation time. However, I did get longer computation time, but it seems the network no longer works since the accuracy does not look right.

```
--cat--
Classification time: 1.0368 seconds
0.0015 - "n04435653 tile roof"
0.0015 - "n04209239 shower curtain"
0.0014 - "n03530642 honeycomb"
0.0014 - "n03729826 matchstick"
0.0014 - "n04033901 quill, quill pen"

--dog--
Classification time: 1.0506 seconds
0.0015 - "n04435653 tile roof"
0.0015 - "n04209239 shower curtain"
0.0014 - "n03530642 honeycomb"
0.0014 - "n03729826 matchstick"
0.0014 - "n04033901 quill, quill pen"
```

I am wondering does Caffe framework support different data type precisions at all? Is that because the network was trained by using float, so it won't work with other data type precisions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mean file and the trained parameter you are using in the tutorial are stored in single precision values. Changing `float` to `double` in the program does not change the stored values, thus trying to read stored single-precision values as double-precision results with you reading "garbage". You'll have to manually convert the files to double precision values

Comment: Thanks. If changing `float` to `double` in the program does not change the stored values, why the final classification results changed?

Comment: @LeiXun the stored values are 32bit float, but when compiled with double, Caffe tries to read as 64bits float.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "reading stored single-precision values as double-precision results with you reading "garbage""?

Comment: @LeiXun values are stored (on disk or in memory) as a long sequence of bits. These bits can have different meaning, depending how you "interpret" them when you read them. Consider the 8bits value of 0xEF: if you interpret this as unsigned char - you get the value of 239. However, if you interpret is a signed char - you get the value -17, and if you decide to read the same bits as `char` you get ``` (accute accent). The same goes for bits stored as 32 float numbers, if you interpret them (when reading) as 64bit floating point you get completely different values.

Comment: Thanks. Your clarification is really helpful.